# Ubuntu 16.04 MySQL hash creation vs Htpasswd hash

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to create hashes in SQL for a long list of users.

If I use `htpasswd -c /tmp/testfile joe` (followed by mama as the password) I get the following result:

```
cat testfile
joe:$apr1$9Ba0JDuU$j7qiNqwhiJJVrxg8v5Jcu/
```

However if I do that same command in mysql I come up with a different hash, whether I specify MD5 or SHA.. any ideas?

```
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
| user| pass hash                                 |
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
|joe  | eeafbf4d9b3957b139da7b7f2e7f2d4a          | (md5)
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
|joe  | 99df988b77e60a1718e9e6fecdaf22552047be28  | (sha1) 
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
|joe  | 99df988b77e60a1718e9e6fecdaf22552047be28  | (sha)
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the command `htpasswd -c /tmp/testfile joe` once again and you will see the hashed password will be different. This is exactly the way in which the hash function shall work. If the two hashes were equal is will be easy to find the password. Find more in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: so I read that apache uses more than just the standard sha hash, there's some algorithm involving salts.

my question is what's the standard way to import lists of users and then get them loaded into mysql? perhaps some kind of shell script using htpasswd?